# Problems installing ShortRead package in R -- can't install RCurl dependency

Tags: r, rcurl, bioconductor

I'm working with Bioconductor and I would like to install the ShortRead package. i've tried many times but I come to an error installing the dependency package RCurl. I get this error in RStudio:

```
            Cannot find curl-config
```

What shall I do? Is there an alternative to ShortRead?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

- What OS are you using?
- `sessionInfo ()`?
- is libcurl (probably you need the dev version) installed? RCurl links to libcurl. [RCurl's CRAN page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html) says:

> SystemRequirements:  libcurl (version 7.14.0 or higher) http://curl.haxx.se. On Linux systems, you will often have to explicitly install libcurl-devel to have the header files and the libcurl library.

Comment: The questions "What OS are you using?" and "sessioninfo()?" belong in the comments. Could you also provide a link to the CRAN page that you quoted from?

Comment: @Firefeather: considering that the question is 1 1/2 years old, I don't think putting a new comment now will help in any way. I added the likt to RCurl's CRAN page, even though that is the only R package in the whole question and answer (the dependency is still the same).

Comment: Oops! I didn't notice the age. Sorry; I guess you could consider what I said as general advice for the future. Thanks for adding the link–I have a hard time navigating CRAN, and I imagine that is helpful to more than just me.